# IntelliJ IDEA: How to disable "Code Generation"?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'd like to know how can I disable "Code Generation" message which keeps on showing as I type code. My auto completion lags a bit so I'd like to experiment a 
little to see if disabling it will speed up my IDE.

[image]

IDE Info:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2
Build #IC-162.1121.32, built on July 9, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_45-b14 amd64
JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
```

Regards,

Ezekiel

Comment: The IDE has no such functionality. It's likely caused by some third-party plugin. Please try to disable them.

Comment: Thank you! As soon as I disabled the Xtend and Xtext plugin, the code generation no longer shows. That's a little surprising because I'm not editing xtend files.

Comment: I had the same issue with the same Xtend and Xtext plugins Thanks! Bad plugin behavior, IMHO. I'm not writing any Xtend code. It has been bothering me for months!